# json variable is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a json file in a folder called json/img_desc.json

Here is the json file

```
{ "theimages":[
  {
    "number":1,
    "title":"Joy Toy teddy bear",
    "description":"In etc etc"
  } etc etc
```

Then I used this code to try and get the first value.

```
 $.getJSON('json/img_desc.json', function(theimages) {
    console.log(img_desc.theimages.number[0]);
});
```

**The error**

It says this

> [15:06:46.951] ReferenceError: img_desc is not defined @
>   file:///[removed for privacy]/js/puzzle.js:246

Comment: use  console.log(theimages.number[0]);

Answer (score 5):

it should be

```
$.getJSON('json/img_desc.json', function (theimages) {
    console.log(theimages.theimages[0].number);

    //if you want to loop
    $.each(theimages.theimages, function (idx, obj) {
        console.log(obj.number)
    })
});
```

Comment: thanks, this worked. However I have another error it says my json file is "not-well formed" ? Is this a problem? Line 1 Json file: { "theimages":[

Comment: complete your closing tag @Ghozt

Comment: It is closed. ] } is the last line

Comment: in FireFox if that makes a difference

Comment: @Ghozt looks like there is syntax issues in the file... can you share the file contents

Comment: FireFox specifies the first line as the error:[15:21:40.542] not well-formed @ file:///[removed]/funzzles/json/img_desc.json:1

Comment: It works and I validated the json with json lint, so it must just be a firefox issue? Thank you btw!

Answer (score 2):

Documentation says http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/#jQuery-getJSON-url-data-success-data--textStatus--jqXHR- it will pass a plain object as the second parameter. So, you can do something like this

```
$.getJSON('json/img_desc.json', function(theimages) {
    $.each(theimages.theimages, function( index, val ) {
        console.log(val, val.number);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $.getJSON('json/img_desc.json', function(img_desc) {
    console.log(img_desc.theimages.number[0]);
});
```

Should fix your problem. As if you have any other problem, ask it in a separate question.